# How to Use Radio Buttons in Mvc3+Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am Working with Mvc3+Razor, How can i embed Radio buttons in my view.
Example: I have Two Options when I click on first second one should be disable, and I have another query that is how can we get Radio button values in Throw Jquery. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td style="background-color:#FFE4B5;color:#008080">
<label>@Html.RadioButton("Gender","True")Male</label></td>
<td style="background-color:#FFC0CB;color:#FF6347"><label>@Html.RadioButton("Gender",  
"False")Female</label></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enum to hold the selected value.

```
 public enum Selection
 {
   Option1,
   Option2
 }

 public class ViewModel
 {
   public Selection SelectedValue {get;set;}
 }

 View:
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValue, "Option1")
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValue, "Option2")
```